# Limitations in Visual Studio 2008 when using limited account privileges

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Unfortunately I lack admin rights on my machine at work. This makes me wonder, what limitations are there when doing development in Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition? I believe one of these limitations may be in not being able to write to the file system?

What else applies? Can I write to "My Documents" (using XP Pro)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most day to day operations, running Visual Studio as a non-administrative user prevents no problems.  I run it as a limited user on pretty much all of my machines are rarely encounter an issue with doing so.

That being said there are a couple of limitations

- Can run certain types of profile operations as a limited user
- Certain remote debugging scenarios require admin priviledges
- In a default configuration, deploying to local IIS installations in II6 requires admin privs

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I know is not possible without admin permissions is to have a Web APplication Project that has the "Use IIS" setting set to true under the web options.

Comment: It is possible to work around this limitation.  http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2005/02/04/367137.aspx